# Lawvere theories with two generic objects

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, examples-counterexamples

What is the simplest example of a category with finite products and two objects $X,Y$ such that

- $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic,
- $X$ is isomorphic to $Y^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
- $Y$ is isomorphic to $X^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

This should demonstrate that the generic object of a [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) is not uniquely determined. Rather, it shows that the *correct* definition of a Lawvere theory is a *pair* $(\mathcal{L},X)$ consisting of a category with finite products and an object $X \in \mathcal{L}$ such that every object of $ \mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to some $X^n$. It is not enough to state the existence of such an object as a property.

I am not sure if [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3) answers the question (does it?), but in any case there must be simpler examples (since here any category can be chosen).

**Edit.** In fact, a theorem of Ketonen implies that there are boolean algebras $A$ such that $A \cong A^4$ and $A \not\cong A^2$, and then $X := A$ and $Y := X^2$ are a counterexample. I am looking for an answer which either explains this algebra $A$ in a self-contained way and gives a proof of $A \not\cong A^2$ and $A \cong A^4$, or (perhaps even) better gives an example in a more elementary category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple explicit example (I believe it is equivalent to Alex Kruckman's example, but it gives an explicit set-theoretic construction that makes it easier to see why $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic).  For convenience I will consider the dual question with coproducts instead of products.  Let $A$ be a set with $4$ elements and let $X=A^\mathbb{N}$.  Note that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have a canonical bijection $A^n\times X\to X$ given by concatenation of sequences.  If $T$ is a set, we can think of $T\times X$ as consisting of $|T|$ copies of $X$, but we can also think of it as consisting of $4|T|$ copies of $X$ by identifying it with $T\times A\times X$, or as consisting of $16|T|$ copies of $X$ by identifying it with $T\times A^2\times X$, or as consisting of $4^n|T|$ copies of $X$ for any $n$ by identifying it with $T\times A^n\times X$.  Say that a copy of $X$ in $T\times X$ has *depth $n$* if it is one of the $4^n|T|$ copies obtained in this way.  Say that a function $f:X\to T\times X$ is *good* if it is the inclusion of a copy of $X$ at some depth.  That is, $f$ is good if there exists $t\in T$ and a finite sequence $a\in A^n$ for some $n$ such that $f(x)=(t,ax)$ for all $x\in X$, where $ax$ denotes the concatenation of $a$ and $x$.  Note that if we take a good function and restrict it to one of the copies of $X$ inside $X$ (identifying $X$ with $A^m\times X$ for some $m$), we get another good function, since this corresponds to just extending the finite sequence $a$ used.

Our category has as objects the sets of the form $S\times X$ where $S$ is finite.  The morphisms are the *locally good* functions: that is, functions that are good when restricted to each copy of $X$ in $S\times X$ of sufficiently large depth.  More precisely, a function $f:S\times X\to T\times X$ is locally good if for some $n$, if we identify $S\times X$ with $(S\times A^n)\times X$ via concatenation, then the restriction of $f$ to $\{a\}\times X$ is good for each $a\in S\times A^n$.  Since the restriction of a good function to a smaller copy of $X$ is still good, a locally good function $f$ which satisfies the definition above for some depth $n$ will also satisfy it for any larger $n$.  It follows that the composition of two locally good functions is good, since you can choose $n$ large enough for the first function such that it maps each copy of $X$ into a copy of $X$ on which the second function is also good.  Since locally good functions can be defined independently on each of the copies of $X$ making up their domain, $(S\sqcup T)\times X$ is a coproduct of $S\times X$ and $T\times X$ in this category.  The intuition here is that our category knows that $X\sqcup X\sqcup X\sqcup X\cong X$ via the canonical bijection $A\times X\to X$, and only contains the morphisms that can be built out of this isomorphism by decomposing the domain and codomain using this isomorphism repeatedly and then mapping each copy of $X$ in the domain to one of the copies in the codomain via the identity.

Now suppose $f:S\times X\to T\times X$ is an isomorphism in this category.  Then $f$ is a bijection, and there exists $n$ such that $f$ is good on each copy of $X$ of depth $n$ in $S\times X$.  So, $f$ maps each copy of $X$ of depth $n$ in $S\times X$ to some copy of $X$ in $T\times X$.  We would like to "count" the copies of $X$ that $f$ is pairing up in order to get some relationship between $|S|$ and $|T|$.  We have $4^n|S|$ copies of $X$ of depth $n$ on which $f$ is good, but our counting is complicated by the fact that the images of these copies under $f$ might not all have the same depth in $T\times X$.  However, we can think of copies of low depth as just consisting of many copies of higher depth (since each time we increase the depth we split each copy of $X$ into $4$ copies).  Picking $m$ large enough such that all our copies in $T\times X$ have depth at most $m$, if $f$ maps a copy of $X$ to a copy of $X$ of depth $i$, we can think of it instead as mapping it onto $4^{m-i}$ copies of depth $m$.  So we have $4^n|S|$ copies in our domain and $4^m|T|$ copies in our codomain, and each copy in the domain is mapped onto a power of $4$ number of copies in the codomain.  This means that $f$ decomposes the integer $4^m|T|$ as a sum of $4^n|S|$ integers, all of which are powers of $4$.  Reducing this sum mod $3$, this means that $|S|$ and $|T|$ must be the same mod $3$.

So, in particular, $X\not\cong X\sqcup X$ in this category.  On the other hand, since $A\times X\cong X$ via concatenation, we do have $X\cong X\sqcup X\sqcup X\sqcup X$.  So taking $Y=X\sqcup X$, each of $X$ and $Y$ is a coproduct of two copies of the other, but $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic.

(More generally, if you take $A$ to have $N$ elements instead of $4$, then this category will satisfy $S\times X\cong T\times X$ iff $S$ and $T$ are either both empty or both nonempty and $|S|$ and $|T|$ are the same mod $N-1$.  You are then just asking for two distinct residues mod $N-1$ which are each multiples of each other, which exist as long as $N\geq 4$.)

Comment: Thank you! This looks very interesting. Unfortunately I already have problems with "seeing" that locally good functions are closed under composition. And why is the identity locally good? There is so much stuff going on in the definition (identifications, restrictions, shifts, ...), I am afraid that I have to compute this in great detail, which looks tedious, but I assume that you somehow did not need to do this. How? Even more I ask myself how you "see" that $(S \sqcup T ) \times X$ is the coproduct of $S \times X$ and $T \times X$.

Comment: And unforunately I don't see the connection between your definition of locally good functions and the intuition you mention.

Comment: I have added more detail.  If you are used to visualizing the Cantor set then that may help with the intuition--$X$ is like the Cantor set except it splits into 4 smaller copies of itself instead of just 2.  So our objects are like disjoint unions of Cantor sets, and the maps are maps which send sufficiently small copies of the Cantor set onto other small copies of the Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I guess this is an "explicit representation" of the category of 4-ary Jonsson-Tarski algebras (or one of its subcategories)?

Comment: This should be an explicit representation of the category of finitely generated free 4-ary Jónsson-Tarski algebras, with $S\times X$ corresponding to the free algebra on $S$.  Or, the set of locally good maps $X\to S\times X$ *is* (the underlying set of) the free 4-ary Jónsson-Tarski algebra on $S$.

Comment: You may find it valuable to compare this representation with the description of a normal form for elements of free Jónsson-Tarski algebras I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3544816/86856) (that is for 2-ary Jónsson-Tarski algebras, but it has an obvious generalization to the 4-ary case).  In the notation of that answer, the element $p_a(s)$ for a string $a$ and corresponds to taking the good map $X\to S\times X$ given by $x\mapsto(s,ax)$.  Combining these elements with the operation $w$ then corresponds to building a locally good map out of several good maps.

Answer (score 9):

Why not take the free category with finite products generated by an object $X$ and an isomorphism $X\cong X^4$? Then taking $Y = X^2$, we have $X\cong Y^2$, but $X\not\cong Y$ (because there some object $A$ in some category with finite products in which $A\cong A^4$ but $A\not\cong A^2$, as shown in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/252553/2126) to the question you linked to - e.g. in the category of Boolean algebras, by the theorem of Ketonen).

This is the Lawvere theory of $4$-ary [Jónsson-Tarski algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3nsson%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra). It can be presented as an algebraic theory in a language with a $4$-ary operation $\mu$ and $4$ unary operations $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3, \pi_4$ and equations $\mu(\pi_1(x),\pi_2(x),\pi_3(x),\pi_4(x)) = x$ and $\pi_i(\mu(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)) = x_i$ for $1\leq i \leq 4$.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for an example which is less universal (perhaps a quotient of the universal example then), more easy to verify and more self-contained - in particular without Ketonen's theorem. Again since we are free to choose the category, I hope that we don't need to work with complicated boolean algebras.

Comment: Well, there may be a more straightforward way to show that $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic (equivalently, the free $4$-ary Jónsson-Tarski algebras on one and two generators are not isomorphic). That would be interesting to know.